# How to upload an article to arXiv.org that uses TikZ 3.0?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arxiv

Since arXiv is still using outdated libraries, it doesn't have an up to date TikZ version, which is very inconvenient for me since I'm using TikZ 3.0. Consequently, I get lots of error messages when I submit my article like missing `tikzlibraryquotes.code.tex` or `tikz-cd` isn't working properly or doesn't accept certain arguments.

What do I do?

Comment: externalise your images

Comment: @percusse, if you use `tikz-externalise`, your article will still try to use the same packages, so e.g. the error with `tikzlibraryquotes.code.tex` will not go away

Comment: I meant only externalize not TikZ library

Comment: @percusse, then I don't understand what your solution is. Can you post an answer?

Comment: It seems you're referring to the standalone package `tikz-externalise`, which doesn't use TikZ. In principle, this may work, but it doesn't work well with TikZ-cd

Comment: arXiv will be rebuilding their TeX in the next few months. You might try again once they roll out the new build.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Until arXiv have updated their TexLive distribution, and you don't want to upload your graphics as separate, precompiled files, you can only upload *all of TikZ and PGF* together with your article. Here is how (assuming Linux):

Create an empty directory `pgftikz` and copy all files that belong to TikZ and PGF in there, without the directory structure ("flatly"):

```
find /usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/ -type f -exec cp {} pgftikz/ \;
```

The path of your TikZ and PGF package might differ.

Put all these files in a `.tar.gz` archive (without the `pgftikz` directory) and upload that to your submission.

Comment: You are basically shipping the package with your article. I am not sure if this is a solution.

Comment: @percusse, it's a nasty, nasty workaround, and I asked the arXiv admin whether it really has to be done, but he stopped responding at some point.

Comment: Just wanted to say that arXiv people have finally responded, they're busy people :)

Comment: And what did they say in their response?  I've done a similar thing to use breqn in a submission which needs to be updated soon.

Comment: @msk, I had already uploaded the article with the above strategy, so there was nothing else to be said

Comment: On OS X, using MacTeX, you'll need to replace the path above with `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/`, changing the year as appropriate.

Comment: Any idea on how to locate these files in Windows under Miktex?

Comment: This didn't work for me. Should nothing be changed to the .tex-file?

Comment: @Teun in the meantime, arXiv have long updated their TeXLive distribution. Hopefully you won't need this workaround.

Comment: @Turion Well I don't know why, but my Tikz-images don't show up properly when compiled by arXiv. All lines and dots are missing. But you are correct, so maybe this is caused by something else.

Answer (score 1):

arXiv just updated to TeXLive 2016 last week, see https://arxiv.org/new#feb10_2017