# Tikzset not processed by arXiv

Tags: tikz-styles, arxiv

I have a custom tikzset with code provided by: [Use something like underbrace to show differences in progression](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341270/use-something-like-underbrace-to-show-differences-in-progression). To be self-contained, here is the Latex I'm using directly:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\tikzset{%
pics/underbrace/.style args={#1,#2,#3}{%
% a pic for putting an underbrace under certain columns
% #1 = left column
% #2 = right column index
% #3 = label text
code = {
       \pgfextractx\colL{\pgfpointanchor{M-1-#1}{south}}  % x-coords of columns
       \pgfextractx\colR{\pgfpointanchor{M-1-#2}{south}}
       % draw the delimiter with the correct width
       \node[rectangle, below delimiter={\}}, minimum width=\dimexpr\colR-\colL-1pt]
              at ($ (M-1-#1)!0.5!(M-1-#2) $){};
       % the label
       \node at ($ (M-1-#1.south)!0.5!(M-1-#2.south) $)[below=1mm]{$\scriptstyle #3$};
       }
    },
 }
\matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes,row sep=1cm,column sep=1mm]{
  x! & 2x! & 3x! & \ldots & (n-x-1)x! & (n-x)x! & (x+1)!\\
 };
 \pic{underbrace={1,2,2}};
 \pic{underbrace={2,3,3/2}};
 \pic{underbrace={5,6,\tfrac{n-x}{n-x-1}}};
 \pic{underbrace={6,7,\tfrac{x+1}{n-x}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It works nicely to produce a pdf locally, but the tikzset is causing my tex to not be accepted by arXiv. The relevant error message is as follows:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.879 \pic
{underbrace={1,2,2}};
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.879 \pic
{underbrace={1,2,2}};
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I'm assuming this is an issue with arXiv using an older version of Latex. Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: Essentially see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287613, either maker PDFs of the diagrams, or upload all of TikZ along with the manuscript.

Comment: Unfortunate that this is necessary, but I used a picture and got it working. Thank you.